# javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: mac check in GCM failed

Tags: java, android, kotlin, encryption, aes-gcm

I'm developing Android client. What we have:

1. Server ecnrypts data by AES algorithm with GCM;
2. Server sends it to client by REST API;
3. Client has to decrypt data and display it.

I stuck on 3 step. My question is how to decrypt arrived data. This is what I tried already:

```
class PrivateInfoDecrypter {

    companion object {
        const val SECRET_KEY = "secret_key"
    }

    private val bytes = ByteArray(16)
    private val gcmParameterSpec: GCMParameterSpec = GCMParameterSpec(128, bytes)

    fun decrypt(input: String, smsCode: String): String {
        val keySpec = generateKey(smsCode)

        val cipher: Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding")
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, gcmParameterSpec)

        val original = cipher.doFinal(input.toByteArray())

        return String(original)
    }

    private fun generateKey(smsCode: String): SecretKeySpec {
        val spec: KeySpec = PBEKeySpec(smsCode.toCharArray(), SECRET_KEY.encodeToByteArray(), 65536, 256)
        val f: SecretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1")
        val key: SecretKey = f.generateSecret(spec)

        return SecretKeySpec(key.encoded, "AES")
    }

}
```

I get this error in logcat:

```
E/Whoops: javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: mac check in GCM failed
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
    at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher$AEADGenericBlockCipher.doFinal(BaseBlockCipher.java:1367)
    at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineDoFinal(BaseBlockCipher.java:1100)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2056)
```

Encryption side: (server side code)

```
    private static final byte[] bytes = new byte[16];
    static final GCMParameterSpec gcmParameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, bytes);

    String encrypt(String input) throws Exception {
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(otpCode.toCharArray(), secretKey.getEncoded(), 65536, 256);
        SecretKeyFactory f = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        byte[] key = f.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, gcmParameterSpec);
        var salted = getPseudoSaltedValue(val);
        return new String(Hex.encode(cipher.doFinal(salted.getBytes())));
    }
```

Comment: At the moment your question is not answerable without seeing the encryption side, even if it should be in a different language. The reason is easy - the GCM mode provides additional security by adding an HMAC value but it differs from language to language and implementation how this value ("GCM tag") is transported. Secondly: In your GCMParameterSpec the value is always 16 zero bytes - this would be horrible for the security of the complete encryption. Kindly add the encryption code to your question.

Comment: Decryption lacks the hex decoding of the ciphertext, apart from that decryption works on my machine (if consistent data is used in encryption and decryption and the non-posted `getPseudoSaltedValue()` is omitted).

Comment: @Topaco it means server must send IV to client with encoded data?

Comment: In the code, both the IV (actually 12 bytes for GCM) for encryption (s. 1st comment) and the salt (referred to here as `secretKey`) for key derivation are static (usually both are randomly generated for each encryption and sent along with the ciphertext, e.g. concatenated). With AES/GCM, it's for security reasons crucial that a key/IV pair may only be used once. For this to be fulfilled with a static IV, the key (or with likewise static salt, the password, here referred to as `optCode`/`smsCode`) would have to be changed for each encryption.

Comment: @Topaco in both sides (server and client) identical IV is being used (byte array with 16 zeros). But I'm still catching the same error. It means problem's in generated key?

Comment: The static IV and salt are a potential security issue, but are not the cause of the decryption failure. The actual bug in the Kotlin code is the missing hex decoding of `input` in the decryption (i.e. the inverse of `Hex.encode()` in the Java code). Have you fixed this issue?

Comment: @Topaco yeah I realized that problem may be in hex encoding/decoding, I'm working on it right now

Comment: I am facing the same exception while encryption. Could anyone help. my so question link . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71304327/javax-crypto-aeadbadtagexception-mac-check-in-gcm-failed-android-aes-gcm-encry